# Prevent add_filter being applied to wp-admin pages

Tags: filters, wp-admin

I'm applying a filter to a custom fields plugin.

```
add_filter('acf/load_value', word_swap);
```

My problem is this applies it to pages within the wp-admin also. I only want the filter applied to the actual WP site, and not the admin panel.

How can I prevent the filter being applied to the wp-admin pages?

I imagine I'd do something like

```
if(page == 'wp-admin')
   add_filter('acf/load_value', word_swap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `!is_admin()` check. This will return false on admin pages, failing your condition. On front end pages, that condition will return true, executing your conditional statement

```
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    // Do something only on frontend
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `is_admin()` is available before any plugin is loaded. So you can use it when you are registering the callback:

```
is_admin() or add_filter('acf/load_value', 'word_swap' );
```